# How can I select file from icloud or dropbox, drive to upload in Titanium Appcelerator

Tags: titanium, dropbox, appcelerator, icloud, appcelerator-titanium

Anybody help me on how can I select file from iCloud or Dropbox, Drive to upload in Titanium Appcelerator. I'm working on a upload document function

Comment: Any suggestion for this question? I have the same issue. I looking something like whatsapp send file, user able to select either dropbox, google drive or icloud to select the file for sending.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to integrate a module that wraps the DropBox or iCloud SDKs:

- http://gitt.io/search?q=dropbox
- https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/11236